# C++ - Values change unexpectedly

Tags: c++

For some reason, the values of a passed struct change without me accessing them. I found this out by debugging with Visual Studio. Here is the code:

```
bool Screen::blitSurface(SDL_Surface* src, int x, int y, SDL_Rect* rect) {
  SDL_Rect* offset;
  offset->x = x;
  offset->y = y;

  SDL_BlitSurface( src, rect, screen, offset );

  return true;
}
```

The struct that is changing is 'rect'. When it is passed, rect->x is 0 and rect->y is 16. However, at the next breakpoint (offset->x = x;) rect->x is a random number (for instance, -13108), same with rect->y. Does anybody have an idea as to why this happens? I'm completely lost, and have no idea where to start.

--EDIT--

Ok, I updated the code to this, but it's still having the problem.

```
bool Screen::blitSurface(SDL_Surface* src, int x, int y, SDL_Rect* rect) {
  SDL_Rect offset;
  offset.x = x;
  offset.y = y;

  SDL_BlitSurface( src, rect, screen, &offset );

  return true;
}
```

However, it did get me thinking. If I create a local struct, and return a pointer to it, it is deleted once the function completes? For example, does this work?

```
SDL_Rect* getRect(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
  SDL_Rect rect;

  rect.x = x;
  rect.y = y;
  rect.w = width;
  rect.h = height;

  return &rect;  
}
```

This is where I get the 'rect' variable that I am passing to 'blitSurface'.

Comment: You've not allocated any memory for `offset`; how do you expect this to work?

Comment: Where's "the next breakpoint"? After the function returns? After the call to `SDL_BlitSurface()`?

Comment: It's not `rect` that changes, but `*rect`. It's a bit like the distinction between the spoon and you.

Comment: Now you're returning the address of a local variable. The variable dies after the function exits and you're left with a nonsensical pointer. Return the `SDL_Rect` by value instead.

Answer (score 2):

**This code is wrong:**

```
SDL_Rect* offset;
offset->x = x;
offset->y = y;
```

Here, `offset` is an uninitialized pointer.  Accessing an uninitialized pointer is always an error, even though it doesn't always crash your program.  I wouldn't use a pointer here.

```
SDL_Rect offset;
offset.x = x;
offset.y = y;
SDL_BlitSurface(src, rect, screen, &offset);
```

When you access an uninitialized pointer (or an invalid one), you are basically telling your computer to scribble over an arbitrary part of your computer's memory.  In a best-case scenario, the program crashes.  In a worst-case scenario, it doesn't crash -- think about that for a moment.

**This code is also wrong:**

```
SDL_Rect rect;
// ...
return &rect;
```

The pointer to `rect` is invalid as soon as the function exits.  Again, I wouldn't use a pointer here.

```
SDL_Rect getRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.x = x;
    rect.y = y;
    rect.w = width;
    rect.h = height;
    return rect;
}
```

The `SDL_Rect` structure is small enough and trivial enough that you should feel free to return it from a function.  If you need to pass the result to an SDL function that takes a pointer, do it this way:

```
SDL_Rect r = getRect(...);

SDL_Some_Function(..., &r, ...);
```

**Pointers are dangerous in C and C++:** That's not to say you shouldn't use them.  But if you don't know exactly what conditions make a pointer valid or invalid, then your program will be incorrect.  The compiler will not help you figure this out -- although static analysis tools like Clang might help.

Unlike C and C++, most other languages (like Python, C#, Java, Haskell, Lisp, Perl, Ruby) do not allow you to create invalid pointers unless you really work at it.

Comment: Even if the pointer were initialized (like `SDL_Rect * offset = 5;`) it wouldn't help. Rather, the pointer needs to *have a valid value*.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, you're right.  I didn't explicitly enumerate all possible wrong things that could happen.

Answer (score 2):

Two words: **Undefined behavior**.

```
  SDL_Rect* offset;
  offset->x = x;
  offset->y = y;
```

You're accessing an uninitialized variable.

Either allocate `offset`:

```
SDL_Rect* offset = new SDL_Rect;
```

or have it in automatic memory:

```
  SDL_Rect offset;
  offset.x = x;
  offset.y = y;

  SDL_BlitSurface( src, rect, screen, &offset );
```